# How to make a signature field in LaTeX

Tags: latex

When I'm writing my laboratory reports in LaTeX, I recently had to make a signature field on the form.

```
                   Trondheim 4.september 2009


______________________         ___________________________
  Ivar Nesje                      Team mate's name
```

The problem was that I could not find a easy way to do it so after a lot of searching on the net I came up with this simple solution

```
\newcommand{\doubleSignature}[3]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\vspace{2cm}

\makebox[12cm][c]{
 #1, \today 
}
\vspace{3cm}

\makebox[12cm][c]{
\hfill \makebox[5cm][c] {\hrulefill} \hfill \makebox[5cm][c] {\hrulefill} \hfill
}
\makebox[12cm][c]{
\hfill #2 \hfill #3 \hfill
}
\vspace{1cm}
\end{minipage}
}
```

This allowed me to type;

```
\doubleSignature{Trondheim}{Ivar Nesje}{Team mate's name}
```

To achieve the wanted result. If any of you have another way of doing this, not using the letter document class, I'd be really glad to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I would work from [`\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<thickness>}`](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/doc/html/texhelp/ltx-306.html). Because the reference point is the lower left corner, you probably don't even need the optional raising argument. Something like:

```
\newcommand{\doublesignature}[3][Ivar Nesje]{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \centering #3 \today\\
    \vspace{2cm}

    \parbox{7cm}{
      \centering
      \rule{6cm}{1pt}\\
       #1 
    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{7cm}{
      \centering
      \rule{6cm}{1pt}\\
      #2
    }
  }
}
```

I've re-ordered your arguments to make your name optional.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there aren't additional formatting restrictions, I probably would have used a `tabular` environment instead of boxes, and I would have used `\rule{length}{width}` instead of `\hrulefill`:

```
\newcommand{\doubleSignature}[3]{
\vspace{2cm}

\begin{center}
    #1, \today
\end{center}
\vspace{3cm}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \rule{5cm}{1pt} & \hspace{2cm} & \rule{5cm}{1pt} \\
    #2 & & #3
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}
}
```